# How do I close entries in my alt-tab menu?

Tags: 12.04, menu

That's right, I want to close a bunch of stuff using my <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> window, quickly.  Let's say I have a bunch of windows open in an image editing program, for example:

[image: a screenshot of my alt-tab menu]

I'd like to have a hotkey (e.g., <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) I can press while the <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> menu is up that will close the currently selected window.

Is a hotkey for this?

Comment: The one answer there doesn't work for me; trying it led to my browser (the last active window) being closed.  Can someone else verify that "press the backtick then F4" is the right solution?

Comment: In case you haven't found the answer yet, here's the link which answers your question: [http://askubuntu.com/a/601570](http://askubuntu.com/a/601570) I've verified the answer and it works.