# Quickly close or hide an app with ubuntu

Tags: unity, launcher, 16.10

As I have a MBP with a narrow screen (13-inch), I'd like to hide the Launcher (See `System Setting` > `Appearance` > `Behavior` > `Auto-hide the Launcher`) in Ubuntu to gain a settle more space. If I do that, is there exist a shortcut on the board to display something related to the spotlight bar with OSX or something like the application 4- on this [website](http://trendblog.net/15-awesome-mac-os-x-hidden-features-dont-know-gifs/) with OSX I can apply under Ubuntu?

**P.S.** I have MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012), and I'm using Ubuntu as a Virtual Machine under VB.

Also, my host key is bound to <kbd>Left ⌘</kbd>:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Application Switcher

You can show what is described in "application 4" of the post you linked in your question by holding <kbd>ALT</kbd>and pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> for each time you want to move to the next item in the list of open applications.

*Note: If you have more than one window open of a particular application, such as Google Chrome, you can access those different windows by just leaving the selection on the application icon during the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> menu for a small duration, and it will then expand to show the different windows of that application. From there, you can continue to press <kbd>TAB</kbd> until the wanted window is selected.*

#### Closing a window from <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>

There is no officially supported way of doing this, but there is a workaround mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509400/quit-applications-while-switching-with-alt-tab).

### "Spotlight" Search

As for the spotlight search, just press the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key (the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key is either the Windows key on your keyboard or, on Macs, the <kbd>⌘</kbd> (Command) key) once and the search function will appear.

*Tip: You can hold the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key to display a list of all keyboard shortcuts.*

#### *Notes*

If you're using a virtual machine and only have one <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key on your keyboard, then make sure that it's not assigned as the host key for the virtual machine, as it won't register inside of the virtual machine operating system. The OP's solution was that the host key was bound to <kbd>Left ⌘</kbd>, so <kbd>Right ⌘</kbd> worked inside the virtual machine.